# publishing a web app in airwatch

Tags: web-applications, publishing, mdm, airwatch

I am working on publishing native / hybrid / web apps in airwatch. I have figured out publishing native / hybrid apps in airwatch. How can I publish a web-app (basically a link hosted in my web server) as an app in airwatch ?

By this i mean, when a user logs into the airwatch appstore on the device, he/she should see the web-app as an app icon in the store and when he/she wants to select that, it should run in the browser (if airwatch admin has given him access, of course). That would solve my current implementation.

thanks and regards

Comment: You should take a look to the AirWatch Secure Browser. It can be deployed the same way than others AirWatch apps or through profiling. Maybe you can configure bookmarks with your web-apps

Comment: Web Clips and Bookmarks can be published in the storefront for AirWatch now.  While those would be published there, they would only install a tappable icon on the home screen of the device.  If I read what you're asking for is a tappable icon in the storefront that then redirects to the web site.  If this is the case, that functionality doesn't exist within the AirWatch storefront.  I would recommend issuing a feature request for this.  The other answers here meet your needs for publishing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately AirWatch doesn't treat webclip deployments the same as App Deployments within the console (as of v7.3). While apps can be advertised in the App Catalog for on-demand consumption a webclip, when advertised from the console, will be auto-pushed to all users within the defined smart group / ad group.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your requirement is to open url in Browser so you don't need app for that. You can configure and bookmark your url in Airwatch Browser. So every time you open airwatch browser, it will open your url first.

Second. If you want app, then create a simple Android or iOS app with webview opening your link and publish it using airwatch admin console. 
This app will come on airwatch catalog as an app on your mobile.